# Ignore case-sensitive in bash trim

Tags: bash, sequence, trim

I am trying to change sequence of a repeated character into numbers. Is anyway to ignore case.

I tried using changing all lower cases to upper case.

[trim doc](https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html)

```
echo "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCcCCCCCcCC" | tr c C | tr -s "ABC" "123"
>123
```

Is there a better way to ignore case.

Comment: You can use: `tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCcCCCCCcCC" | tr "ABC" "123"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `GNU Awk` you can use its [`IGNORECASE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) feature for this.

```
echo "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCcCCCCCcCC" | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}{gsub(/[A]+/,"1") ;gsub(/[B]+/,"2"); gsub(/[C]+/,"3")}1'
123
```

Quoting from the `man` page,

> [..] Another method, specific to gawk, is to set the variable `IGNORECASE` to a nonzero value (see Built-in Variables). When `IGNORECASE` is not zero, all regexp and string operations ignore case.
>
> Changing the value of `IGNORECASE` dynamically controls the case sensitivity of the program as it runs. Case is significant by default because `IGNORECASE` (like most variables) is initialized to zero[..]

Comment: You will actually need 3 calls to `gsub` to transliterate each letter to corresponding digit otherwise `AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCcCCCCCcCCaa` will also be converted to `123` instead of `1231`

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks again, knew, it, thought I would make it easily readable by making it a bracket expression `[..]` and character inside as `C`, so people don't confuse it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu sed you can do this with ignore case flag:

```
str='AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBCcCCCCCcCC'

sed -E 's/a+/1/Ig; s/b+/2/Ig; s/c+/3/Ig' <<< "$str"
123
```

Or using `tr`:

```
tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "$str" | tr "ABC" "123"
123
```